# Openwrt iptables has no "string" module

Tags: openwrt

I am a teacher.

I am going to host a "Field Trip" for teenagers.

In class, each student has an iPad or computer to browse Apple official web "apple.com"

To better control the class, I wanna block some pages of "apple.com" like

https://www.apple.com/apple-arcade/

https://support.apple.com

All the iPads or computers will connect to the WiFi router which runs a Openwrt.

I know "iptables" would help.

I know I can use `iptables -A FORWARD -s apple.com -j DROP` to block the whole domain "apple.com".

But don't know how to only block the subdomain ***"support.apple.com"***    or the subpage ***"apple.com/apple-arcade"***

I learned from [this page](https://linuxsecurity101.com/2018/12/01/tips-and-tricks-blocking-http-requests-via-iptables-for-a-specific-domain/), I tried to type in

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: apple.com" --algo kmp -m string --string "GET /apple-arcade" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

but the Terminal warns 
`` iptables v1.8.2 (legacy): Couldn't load match `string':No such file or directory" ``

I tried to `cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches`

Terminal returns:

```
time
statistic
state
mark
mac
limit
helper
conntrack
conntrack
conntrack
connmark
connlimit
connbytes
comment
udplite
udp
tcp
tcpmss
socket
socket
socket
socket
recent
recent
policy
multiport
length
ttl
esp
ecn
tos
dscp
ah
icmp
set
set
set
set
set
```

no "string" in the list.

Dose anyone met the similar problem? How to make "String" available?

Or is there any way to workaround to only block subdomain page or subpage?

Thank you for your reading

Comment: I do not think that this would work, because those two apple.com sites use HTTPS and not HTTP. Oh, the questionable improvement of encryption :-/ Either block apple.com or one/some of its subdomains entirely or descend to DPI(Deep packet inspection) with a MITM HTTPS proxy.